# XML RPC with ARC support?

Tags: ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting, xml-rpc

Does anyone know where I can get the class files for iOS XML-RPC that works with enabled ARC? So far I can't build by project because arc raises all kinds of exceptions.

Comment: You can turn ARC on and off on a per-file basis if you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project

Comment: Also, Xcode has an automatic upgrade to ARC function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that you can compile sources with the

```
-fno-objc-arc
```

flag. this makes a file with the flag compile without ARC.